# How to control the format of this list printing function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like a print function that can print inner list.

The expected result of my function should be:

```
a
b
    aa
    bb
         aaa
         bbb
```

However, now the result is: (the added space is not expected)

```
a
b
        aa
        bb
            aaa
            bbb
```

How can I get the expected result? I have tried my best but failed to figure out a solution. Thanks in advance for any helpers.

```
testlist = ["a","b",["aa","bb",["aaa","bbb"]]]

add_space = False

def printList(the_list, level):

    global add_space

    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            add_space = True
            level += 1
            printList(each_item, level)
        else:
            if add_space == True:
                for numbers in range(level):
                    print("\t",end="")
            print(each_item)


printList(testlist,1)
```

Comment: Just an observation: Your variable names `each_item` and `the_list` only makes sense when declaring your for loop. Inside it, the variable names are weird :p I'd go with....`for item in list` or something.

Comment: Also note that after one call of your `printList` with a nested list `add_space` will always be `True`, which may produce wrong results in next calls if you don't reset it.

Comment: Have you tried `print(" "*(level-1),end="")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global state (the add_space variable) isn't necessary here when the first call to printList is done with level 0 (e.g. printList(testlist, 0)). That simplifies the code and makes it easier to test and debug.

When you add a print statement for the level to your code you'll also see that the level ends up as 2 for the first list item.

And a final small bug: your code increases the level variable when 'each_item' is a list, but doesn't decrease it afterwards. Because of this the indentation will be wrong when you add a new item at the end of the list, just passing level+1 to the recursive call to printList fixes that issue.

Combining all of this:

```
testlist = ["a","b",["aa","bb",["aaa","bbb"]]]

def printList(the_list, level):

    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            printList(each_item, level + 1)
        else:
            for numbers in range(level):
                print("\t",end="")
            print(each_item)


printList(testlist,0)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronald, you gave me a very clear explanation on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using a recursive method.

```
testlist = ["a", "b", ["aa", "bb", ["aaa", "bbb"]]]

def recursive_list_print(lst, level=0):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            recursive_list_print(item, level+1)
        else:
            print('{}{}'.format('\t'*level, item))

recursive_list_print(testlist)
```

Yields:

```
>>> 
a
b
    aa
    bb
        aaa
        bbb
```

Comment: @Keyser Read docs about [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: @Keyser What is there to explain? I use format to combine the tabs required to indent the line and the item to print. The formatter multiplies the tab character by the `level` which is the indentation level the line should have...

Comment: Each `{}` will be replaced by the item from the format list. Here, the first `{}` will become `'\t'*level` and second `{}` will become `item`.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method as

```
printList(testlist,0)
```